# Página wordpress no me utiliza la plantilla definida

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, redirección

Estoy teniendo problemas con una redirección de página en cuanto modifico su enlace permanente para que utilice su `slug` por cambio de idioma (usando polylang).

Lo curioso es que la página cuando tengo el idioma español, sí me aparece la plantilla que he creado pero en inglés no.

El enlace lo construyo de la siguiente forma:

```
 $link = pll__("tienda");
 $url = get_permalink(get_page_by_path($link));
```

Esto me muestra bien cuando es el ID de la página, pero en cuanto tengo el enlace con el slug de la página no me acude a mi plantilla, no entiendo por qué.
La idea es una plantilla para usar también con Woocommerce

Plantilla:

```
<?php    
/**
 * Template name: Portada Tienda
 */    
?>    
<?php get_header();?>
<section class="presenta-tienda">
    <article class="contenedor">
    <div class="textos-website">
        <h2 class="titulo-website">Get it!</h2>
        <p>Hello!</p>
    </div>
    </article>
</section>

<?php
    // Listado de productos de audio
    $query = array("post_type"=>"product","posts_per_page"=>-1,"orderby"=>"menu_order","order"=>"ASC");
    $obj = new WP_Query($query);
    if($obj->have_posts()){
// código para mostrar productos simplemente...
```

Y las páginas están creadas tal que así:
[image: Datos de las páginas]

Y aquí el código que me inserta en mi .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# Las directivas (líneas) entre «BEGIN WordPress» y «END WordPress» son
# generadas dinámicamente y solo deberían ser modificadas mediante filtros de WordPress.
# Cualquier cambio en las directivas que hay entre esos marcadores serán sobrescritas.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /www/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /www/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```